# Overcoming the 'not implemented yet' error when combining model shrinkage with learning continuation in CatBoost

Tags: catboost, boosting, catboostregressor

First of all, thanks to the people that worked on the catboost library, it's amazing!

I am researching the combination of learning continuation, posterior sampling and model shrinkage in gradient boosting. I want to see what happens when I use these techniques together for regression problems.

To note: according to the Catboost [documentation](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/), [posterior sampling](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/references/training-parameters/common#posterior_sampling) is a bootstrap type that enables uncertainty estimation for predictions. [Model shrinkage](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/references/training-parameters/common#model_shrink_mode) is a technique that reduces overfitting by shrinking the weights of the trees over iterations. [Learning continuation](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples#training-continuation) is a way to resume training from a previously saved model.

My question is: How can I implement model shrinkage with learning continuation in CatBoost? Is there some way to get this behaviour without getting the error message? Or are there alternative libraries that offer the posterior sampling and SGLB as well which I should try?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

When I try to set the parameters `loss_function` = 'RMSEWithUncertainty' and `posterior_sampling` = True in CatBoostRegressor and apply learning continuation, I get the following output and error message:

output: 
`0: learn: 3.4441362    total: 372us    remaining: 372us` 
`1: learn: 3.3704627    total: 994us    remaining: 0us` 
`Model shrinkage in combination with learning continuation is not implemented yet. Reset model_shrink_rate to 0.`

error: 
C:/Go_Agent/pipelines/BuildMaster/catboost.git/catboost/libs/train_lib/options_helper.cpp:386: Model shrinkage and Posterior Sampling in combination with learning continuation is not implemented yet.

Here is a code snippet that shows how I use learning continuation with CatBoost:

```py
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor

# Initialize data

train_data = [[1, 4, 5, 6],
              [4, 5, 6, 7],
              [30, 40, 50, 60]]

eval_data = [[2, 4, 6, 8],
             [1, 4, 50, 60]]

train_labels = [10, 20, 30]


# initial parameters
model1 = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=2,
                           learning_rate=0.2,
                           depth=2,
                           loss_function='RMSEWithUncertainty',
                           posterior_sampling=True)
# result will be in model1
model1.fit(train_data, train_labels)

# continue training with the same parameters
model2 = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=2,
                           learning_rate=0.2,
                           depth=2,
                           loss_function='RMSEWithUncertainty',
                           posterior_sampling=True)

# result will be in model2, model1 will be unchanged
model2.fit(train_data, train_labels, init_model=model1)
```

Comment: did you solved it? how?

Comment: No unfortunately not